# How to write loop over complex expressions

Tags: bash, dwm

I am trying to make a script that loops over 
`grep "^\s*w" /proc/net/wireless | awk '{ print int($3 * 100 / 70) "%" }'`
and checks each output case in order to print a proper wifi signal icon like this

```
for x in grep "^\s*w" /proc/net/wireless | awk '{ print int($3 * 100 / 70) "%" }';
        do
        case "$(cat $x)" in
                100|9[0-9])     echo "" ;;
                8[0-9]|7[0-9])  echo "" ;;
                6[0-9]|5[0-9])  echo "" ;;
                4[0-9]|3[0-9])  echo "" ;;
                *)              echo "" ;;
        esac
        done
```

but bash returns an error near '|' expression

Comment: Surroud the commands inside $(): `$(grep "^\s*w" /proc/net/wireless | awk '{ print int($3 * 100 / 70) "%" }'`)

Comment: And you are cating the result, wich is a percentage number not a file. Don't you mean `case "$x" in`

Comment: As well, your cases do not take into account the appended `%` (which seems superfluous). BTW you could omit the `grep` and just do `awk '$1 ~ /^w/ { ... }'`

Comment: You should `grep --line-buffered`, which tells `grep` to flush its output buffer at every NewLine, rather than waiting until it has 4096 bytes of output.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I've removed cat command, and wrapped the grep phraze with $(), it works thank you